# How to avoid chrome bookmarks that have trailing slash and parameter in URL?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I bookmark lot of webpages, and Google chrome show me, weather that page is already bookmarked or not in star icon. If it is filled with blue color then it is already bookmarked and if is blank then it is not bookmarked yet.

[image: bookmark icon]

When I bookmark any URL like `https://www.example.com/page/` and open the same URL again, then it display blue star icon i.e. I already bookmarked that page, but when I open same URL again without trailing slash like `https://www.example.com/page` it display blank star icon i.e. that page is not bookmarked yet. Same thing I face when I open any URL which have some parameters for example `https://www.example.com/page?utm_source=email`

I want to avoid such a duplicate URL in my bookmarks, i.e. can I set any regular express in my browser which say yes that page is already bookmarked, and hence display blue star icon on such URL's.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I set any regular expressions in my browser which say, "Yes, that page is already bookmarked" and hence display a blue star icon on such URLs?

I am going to go out on limb and say most likely not. From the perspective of a web server:

- *https://www.example.com/page* (possibly a file or a directory)
- *https://www.example.com/page/* (a directory)
- *https://www.example.com/page?utm_source=email* (a script)

are all (potentially) different resources. Having an in-browser setting to overcome this treatment for bookmarking purposes would likely break things.

More specifically, the basic issue is the regex itself, what it matches and URL depth. For instance, a regex that matched a main page bookmarked as *www.example.com/index?lang=en* might cause an erroneous "duplicate" issue with a login page on the same site that was accessed with e.g. *www.example.com/index?lang=en&action=login*. Likewise, regex that ignored a certain level of subdirectory could be an issue e.g. *www.example.com/photos/* versus *example.com/photos/Hawaii/*.

---

*If you wish to avoid duplicate bookmarks, a better bet would be to try and install addons to sort and de-duplicate your bookmarks. These certainly exist for Firefox and may for Chrome as well.*

---

Comment: 1. Web pages are not unix based files, so that can break things. Files extension, protocol, trailing slash etc can control by htaccess or nginx server easily. 2. I am not talking sub sub directory 3. Yes there are extension for that, but it does not find duplicate at live time, you've to click on button first, then they tell you how many pages are duplicate.